# Logarithmic Growth in time limit

Tags: calculus

I'm looking for formula that is similar to Exponential Growth formula below, but for [Logarithmic Growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_growth):

Exponential Growth (over time):

$P(t) = P_0 e^{rt}$

```
P(t) = the amount of some quantity at time t 
P0 = initial amount at time t = 0 
r = the growth rate
t = time (number of periods)
```

There is also a more complicated formula for Logistic Growth: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function#In_ecology:_modeling_population_growth

But what I'm looking for is a simpler formula for normal Logarithmic Growth (without saturation and limit parameters and without exponential growth at the  start).